# Oracle getting all the records mentioned in 'IN' Clause

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a query where I get some strings from front end and try to retrieve some records from the database. The problem is that I have added some duplicate strings which get omitted while retrieving the records. I want duplicate data as well for my application.

```
SELECT  c.id,c.cptcode,c.cptname,c.patorder,c.ubcode,p.cptprice,u.description
FROM mstcpt c, 
  (select * from mstcptprice
   where hospitalid = 1034 
   and transactionby ='uhc@viamd.com') p ,
  (SELECT * FROM mstub04) u
WHERE c.cptcode IN ('00','70010 - 76499','00400 - 00479','00100 - 00228',
  '00100 - 00228','00400 - 00479','70010 - 76499', '01670','00','00') 
AND c.cptcode = p.cptcode(+)
and c.ubcode=u.code(+)
```

These are the strings I am getting from the front end:

```
'00'
'70010 - 76499'
'00400 - 00479'
'00100 - 00228'
'00100 - 00228'
'00400 - 00479'
'70010 - 76499'
'01670'
'00'
'00'
```

The results I get currently are:

```
ID     CPTCODE        CPTNAME             PATORDER    UB04CODE  CPTPRICE  DESCRIPTION
31287  00100 - 00228  head1               Lab
31288  00400 - 00479  thorax1             Lab
31530  01670          SHOULDER VEIN SURG  Anesthesia  400   
31204  70010 - 76499  diagnostic imaging  Radiology
```

Desired Output:

```
ID     CPTCODE        CPTNAME             PATORDER    UB04CODE  CPTPRICE  DESCRIPTION
31287  00100 - 00228  head1               Lab
31287  00100 - 00228  head1               Lab
31288  00400 - 00479  thorax1             Lab
31288  00400 - 00479  thorax1             Lab
31530  01670          SHOULDER VEIN SURG  Anesthesia  400   
31204  70010 - 76499  diagnostic imaging  Radiology
31204  70010 - 76499  diagnostic imaging  Radiology
```

How can I get all the data which is mentioned with the number of times I have added it in the front end?

Comment: Presumably your query actually has `in` rather than `like`. I think I understand what you mean, but can you show the desired results as well; or preferably create a simpler test case that demonstrates the issue? And how are the strings being passed from the front end - as bind variables, an array, embedded in the query?

Comment: You say, if `IN` clause has same value _twice_, you want the result too _duplicated_? `IN` logically forms multiple `OR` conditions, so probably unique list of values. So generate a view with those values and join them with your table.

Comment: @OracleUser , so can you give me other solution for this problem. I am not able to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simulate dataset based on values from front-end instead of placing it into `IN` condition:

```
with frontend_values as (
  select '00'            cptcode from dual union all
  select '70010 - 76499' cptcode from dual union all
  select '00400 - 00479' cptcode from dual union all
  select '00100 - 00228' cptcode from dual union all
  select '00100 - 00228' cptcode from dual union all
  select '00400 - 00479' cptcode from dual union all
  select '70010 - 76499' cptcode from dual union all
  select '01670'         cptcode from dual union all
  select '00'            cptcode from dual union all 
  select '00'            cptcode from dual
)
SELECT  
  c.id, c.cptcode, c.cptname, c.patorder, c.ubcode, p.cptprice, u.description
FROM 
  mstcpt                                   c, 
  (
    select * from mstcptprice  
    where hospitalid = 1034 
          and 
          transactionby ='uhc@viamd.com'
  )                                        p ,
  (SELECT * FROM mstub04)                  u ,
  frontend_values                          v 
WHERE 
  c.cptcode = v.cptcode
  and 
  c.cptcode = p.cptcode(+)
  and 
  c.ubcode = u.code(+)
```

Another possibility is to simulate table with `sys.odcivarchar2list` type, but not sure if this works in `Oracle 10g`:

```
SELECT  
  c.id, c.cptcode, c.cptname, c.patorder, c.ubcode, p.cptprice, u.description
FROM 
  mstcpt                                   c, 
  (
    select * from mstcptprice  
    where hospitalid = 1034 
          and 
          transactionby ='uhc@viamd.com'
  )                                        p ,
  (SELECT * FROM mstub04)                  u ,
  (
    table(sys.odcivarchar2list(
      '00', '70010 - 76499', '00400 - 00479', '00100 - 00228', '00100 - 00228',
      '00400 - 00479', '70010 - 76499', '01670', '00', '00' 
    ))
  )                                        v 
WHERE 
  c.cptcode = v.column_value
  and 
  c.cptcode = p.cptcode(+)
  and 
  c.ubcode = u.code(+)
```

Comment: The `odcivarchar2list` option works on 10g too. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
with t as (
  select level id from dual connect by rownum < 5
), t1 as (select 1 id from dual union all select 1 from dual) 
select t.id
  from t, t1
```

In different words, I added a cartesian product of two tables the first one has 4 records, and the second has two records. You have to replace the first table with your dataset.

Comment: This is an example, the author needs to replace t with his datasource and all his rows will be duplicated

Comment: But that will show every row twice, rather than repeating rows based on the number of times each individual string appears in the list?

Comment: I might not have understood the question in the way the author wants. Sorry for confusion